Google Authentication with Python to Google Cloud resources
I am developing an application with Python which consumes resources from Google Cloud. I would like to automate the authentication process  (right now what I have is the authentication via an API Key which allows me to consume the resources the service account has access to).
However, what I want is the user to authenticate via my application to his Google account and only consume from the resources the user has access to. For example, if I am showing data from BigQuery table and the user doesn't have access to it, then he won't be able to work with my application.
I don't have to generate an API key for each user or client, neither I want all the users to consume the same API Key. I would like to have each user authenticated in my application so that I can know which user did what.
Is there any way to do this automatically? Prompt a login interface and have access to the users's Google Cloud resources.
By the way, I am new to the Google Cloud world, so maybe there is some trivial solution but I don't know which is the right way.
I saw in the documentation a lot of ways authenticating but most of the require downloading a json configuration for my own Google Cloud account and I guess this won't work for other users from other organizations, and I don't want to generate a json for each possible user using my application).

When do you talk about a python application, is it a standalone application or a web application? In addition, does all the user have a Google account (gmail, Workspace,...)?

@guillaumeblaquiere I am talking about a web application which uses Google services such as BigQuery (the user's available tables), Speech Recognition, Cloud Storage, ... Also, the user must have a Google account and the Cloud Console configured (I don't know the work required to configure it, but I must be able to, given the user's credentials, be able to create a table in his BigQuery)

WHere are you hosting your website? If on Google Cloud, on which service? Do you have a frontend (static HTML/javacript) and a backend -> and this Backend call the Google Cloud APIs? Or do you try to perform a direct call from the frontend to Google Cloud APIs

@guillaumeblaquiere it's a simple Python dockerized application using Dash so I guess Cloud Run will be fine.  It's just one application, backend + frontend in a same project using Dash.
This python + dash application call the Google Cloud APIs

In that case, I recommend to use IAP with Cloud Run. A little bit cumbersome to set up (and you have to deploy, and pay for a Load Balancer) but it's a great and secure solution: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run
